# What is time complexity of bitwise & operator in java?

Tags: java, operators, time-complexity

I want  to know what is bitwise & operator time complexity in java and how to reduce it using alternative methods if any.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might want to include the relevant Java code in your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to do a[i]&a[j]&a[k]  where a is my int type array so I thought it taking too much time in my code

Comment: Note that time complexity must be defined based on some parameter (such as the "size" of the input, which might be something like string length, number of elements, or type's size in bits).

Comment: 10^5 is length of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the time complexity of `&` operations is `O(n)` where n is the number of 32-bit values or 64-bit values depending on the JVM.

For a single `int` value, the contents don't matter.

> 10^5 is length of array

In this case, the time will be proportional to length of the array.

The fastest way is to use `long` values and store 64-bits in each element.

> no alternative from the user side to reduce this operation time complexity?

An `&` operation of two int values is one of the fastest operations a computer can do and typically takes 1 clock cycle i.e. << 1 ns. This is only a problem if you are doing a lot of them.

Answer (score 2):

The Java bitwise operators operate on primitive operands and are each implemented using a pair of JVM bytecode instructions. Using `&` as an example, those instructions are [`iand`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iand) for `int` and [`land`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.land) for `long`. (In the JVM, the basic word size is 32 bits, and shorter integer types are theoretically stored as 32 bits.) The JVMS does not specify the time complexity of these instructions, but in any sane implementation they'll be implemented using the CPU's bitwise instructions, and so `&` on any particular data type is of constant time regardless of the operands' contents.

Comment: so according to you should I consider that there is no alternative from the user side to reduce this operation  time complexity?

Comment: @AnjuRawat Correct; this is almost the fastest thing you can possibly do in Java. If you actually have a performance problem (which you haven't presented evidence of), it's somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Bit operations are fast and can be used in optimizing time complexity. Some common bit operators are: NOT ( ~ ): Bitwise NOT is an unary operator that flips the bits of the number i.e., if the ith bit is 0, it will change it to 1 and vice versa. Bitwise NOT is nothing but simply the one's complement of a number.

Comment: I know this but im asking about any alternative method to do bitwise & operation